# What is the regex pattern that can match for ASCII and explicit currency symbols

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I'm new to regex and tried searching few regex related questions here. But couldn't find the solution.

I want to check if the String contains only the below:

1) ASCII characters(Currently using `"^\\p{ASCII}*S"`for ASCII alone) or

2) The following currency symbols: **`₺,£,€`**

I know that the currency symbols are not from ASCII, but we can get those values from html and using `StringEscapeUtils.unescapehtml()`and hence want any regex pattern to match only if any of the above conditions are satisfied.

My requirement is :

> If the string has any character other than ASCII and the given symbols, it should return `false`

Comment: Perhaps, `if (!s.matches("[a-zA-Z0-9₺£€]*")) { return false; }`. What do you mean by *ASCII characters*? All ASCII or just letters and digits?

Comment: I'm currently using "^\\p{ASCII}*$" for all ASCII and I just want to extend this to ₺£€ also

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at [the javadoc of the Pattern class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), you will see that there is a character class for ASCII codes. So your code could be something like:

```
Stirng input = ...;
boolean isValid = input.matches("[₺£€\\p{ASCII}]*");
```

That's assuming you want to accept *any* ASCII character.

Comment: Yes, Thanks you.. I was currently using `"^\\p{ASCII}*$"` for all ASCII and I just want to extend this to `₺£€` also... I will try this :)

Answer (score 0):

This regex should do your job -

```
[!-~₺£€]+
```

It matches all printable ASCII characters ie from 33 to 126 plus 3 specific non-ASCII characters you want to check.

Check it here - http://regexr.com/